# Home Lab Routing Not Working

Tags: windows, networking, routing, proxmox

Just to give a quick backstory of my issue, I will try to explain it the best I can.

I have set up a home server running Proxmox (I would have used ESXi, however 6.7 and 7 are not compatible with my CPU as it is an old desktop machine)

The server is connected to my home network (192.168.2.0/24) using ipv4 address 192.168.2.155.

I have a installed multiple VMs and have them all on the 10.10.0.0/24 network and deployed a WinServer2019 VM as my domain controller using the domain "EXAMPLE.COM".

Here is where I am struggling.. I have a PfSense VM handling the routing between the VM's and for internet connection and this is working, however, I am unable to access my VMs using their DNS or IP from my gaming PC. Since my DC is on the 10.10.0.0/24 network and my gaming PC is on the 192.168.2.0/24 network, can anyone shed some light, or at least point me on the right path as to how can I set up my home network to route to this virtual network without using static routes or any additional hardware?

Here is a simple diagram of my network if it helps!

[image: example network diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Configure static routes on your client to reach them. Or configure your router at 192.168.2.1 to forward packages to your other router.

Note that in many cases 192.168.2.1 will send a ICMP redirect to the clients when the clients is in the same subnet as the other router, so a link net may be a good option in this case, linking the routers, but without any clients.